# REGEXP_REPLACE in Postgresql not substring

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace, regexp-replace

In postgresql I would like to substitute just in full words and not substrings. I noticed that replace and translate replace strings even in substrings. Then, I used regexp_replace to add the following:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER('BIG CATDOG'), '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || UPPER('CAT') || '($|[^a-z0-9])', '\1' || UPPER('GATO') || '\2','g')
```

In the previous sample, `CAT` should not been replaced because it is not a whole word, but a substring which is part of a word. How can I achieve to avoid the replacement? The output should be BIG CATDOG because no substitution was possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement happens because you are only checking for `[^a-z0-9]` after the search term, and `D` is not in that character class. You can resolve this by either adding `A-Z` to your character class:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER('BIG CATDOG'), '(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])' || UPPER('CAT') || '($|[^a-zA-Z0-9])', '\1' || UPPER('GATO') || '\2','g')
```

Or by adding the `i` flag to the replace call:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER('BIG CATDOG'), '(^|[^a-z0-9])' || UPPER('CAT') || '($|[^a-z0-9])', '\1' || UPPER('GATO') || '\2','gi')
```

In either case you will get the desired `BIG CATDOG` output.

However a better solution is to use the word boundary constraints `\m` (beginning of word) and `\M` (end of word):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (UPPER('BIG CATDOG'), '\m' || UPPER('CAT') || '\M', UPPER('GATO'),'g')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=60fab0a0b9b408ca7eed156075c2c3fc)

Comment: @JuanPerez no worries. I made an edit just as you responded, using the word boundary constraints is probably a better solution.